# Intermittent Crash: - setObjectForKey: Object cannot be nil (key:ref_id)

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, intermittent

The ref_id object is string/number in the JSON response.
Same code works most of the time. But sometime it crashes (~less than 5%).

```
      NSDictionary *udfDict = nil;
        if (data) {
            if ([data length] > 0) {
                udfDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&serializationError];
            }
        }

        if (udfDict) {
            NSString *transactionreason;
            NSString *refId;
            if (![CustomUtilities isEmptyOrNull:udfDict[@"ref_id"]]) {

                refId = udfDict[@"ref_id"];
                [dict setObject:refId forKey:@"ref_id"];
}
```

Concern: If its not able to downcast from number to string, the code should break all the time.But thats not the case.The crash is intermittent and only code breaks for ~5% occurances.

Comment: `isEmptyOrNull:` code is?

Comment: +(BOOL) isEmptyOrNull:(id)givenString {
    if (givenString == (id)[NSNull null] || givenString == nil) {
        return TRUE;                                                                                         else return FALSE; }

Answer (score 0):

The test whether data != nil is unnecessary. But do yourself and the readers of your code a favour and write if (data != nil) and not if (data). That's barbaric. Same for udfDict. length is a property, so data.length not [data length]. Why are you reading mutable containers? Is this some code that you copied and didn't understand?

Your code will crash if the JSON data is an array.

We don't know what isEmptyOrNull does.

Why setObject and not dict [@"ref_id"] = ... ?

And I don't see any numbers here. What's the actual problem?

Comment: The code breaks here "[dict setObject:refId forKey:@"ref_id"];" I don't think the problem is in "if (data != nil) and not if (data)". Otherwise it won,t come to 3rd If ..else statement mentioned above. Also I have mentioned the code crashes for the same record (Same JSON response) intemittently and not every time.

Comment: Before accessing dict [@"ref_id"] , I am accessing another parameter from dict[@"txn_reason"]. But code never breaks here.